# Setting certain rows in matrix to zero

Tags: numpy, matrix, comparison

In the following code m is a numpy matrix and absm is a matrix copy of the absolute values of matrix m.

```
m[absm < limit] = 0
```

I have used this to turn all matrix values in m to 0 if the corresponding matrix value is absm is smaller than the limit.

This has worked fine, however now I would like to exclude the first n rows of this code, and only turn values into zero if they are in rows below n and I am not quite sure how to go about this.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a mask for that, assuming your matrix is NxM such that N is the number of rows:

```
row_mask = np.arange(N) >= n
m[(absm < limit) & row_mask[:, None]] = 0
```

This uses broadcasting (notice the [:, None] idiom) to apply the & (bitwise and, however, for booleans equivalent to logical and) to your original mask and the row mask. The row mask is actually a 1d vector (shape (N,)) the None indexing adds another dimension so`row_mask[:, None]` is a column vector (shape (N, 1)). Its "thin" dimension is automatically expanded to match your rectangular mask.

Comment: I have given it a go and checked it by printing the conditional statement print((absm < limit) & row_mask[:, None]), although it is printing "False" aka the value we would like to for all the specified top n columns, it is still for some reason allowing to turn the elements in row to 0 which I am yet to wrap my head around

Comment: Did you recreate `m` before trying the new mask? Perhaps you forgot to and used an `m` with the values in the top rows already zeroed out? I can't see why else it wouldn't work.